# Linq expression in Razor view to access child property - how to use view model instead?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, razor

Scenario:

Parent-child relationship between CustomerOrders & CustomerOrderItems in db.

Both CustomerOrders and CustomerOrderItems are defined in the auto-generated Linq2Sql dbml class.

MVC Code:

I have a view model class:

```
public class OrdersListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

which passes data to a partial view (only interested in the CustomerOrders data):

```
@model CallTracking.Domain.Concrete.CustomerOrder
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Auto_ID</td>
    <td>@Model.OrderTotal</td>
    <td>@string.Format("{0} {1}", Model.CustomerFirstName, Model.CustomerSecondName)</td>
    <td>@Model.Email</td>
    **<td>@Model.CustomerOrderItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.SalesPrice).FirstOrDefault().ItemName</td>**
</tr>
```

This works fine, the problem is that I've used a Linq expression in order to display the highest value orderitem for each order record, but I feel (and have read) that I shouldn't use Linq in the view and this should be a property in the view model i.e.

```
public CustomerOrderItem HighestValueOrderItem { get; set; }
```

It's at this point where I get stuck - how & where would I set this value?

Comment: Don't you have access to the CustomerOrderItems collection in your model?

Comment: @rickythefox - I do, but I'm trying to the the highest value item in each Order record, not the whole order collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CustomerOrder Model Create Property Called

```
private CustomerOrderItem _HighestValueOrderItem = null;
public CustomerOrderItem HighestValueOrderItem { 
get{
   if(this.CustomerOrderItems.Any() && _HighestValueOrderItem != null){
        _HighestValueOrderItem =  this.CustomerOrderItems.OrderByDescending(i => i.SalesPrice).FirstOrDefault();
        return  _HighestValueOrderItem;
   } else {
      return new CustomerOrderItem();
   }
}
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks.  (I had to remove '&& _HighestValueOrderItem != null' first though).  I thought I might have to add the property to the model, but I was reluctant because as it's auto-generated ORM code, an update would overwrite my changes.

Answer (score 1):

or, get this value when creating the DTO in the controller

```
public class OrdersListViewModel
{
   public string CurrentItem {get;set;}
   public CustomerOrder[] CustomerOrders { get; set; }
   public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}

//and the controller action
var model = new OrdersListViewModel
                 {
                     CurrentItem = orders.OrderByDescending(i => i.SalesPrice).FirstOrDefault().ItemNumber,
                     CustomerOrders = orders.ToArray(),
                     PagingInfo = new PagingInfo(...)
                 };
return View(model);
```

Comment: cheers for the answer, but unless I'm mistaken, this just gets the highest value order item in the orders collection, whereas I actually want the highest value order item in each order.